# How to find location of view once its drawn

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I've got a view which I am trying to get its location after its drawn.

Below is the code I'm using for that.

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener{
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout(){
        int[] location = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        Log.d("SOME TAG","Location is ("+location[0]+","+location[1]+)");
    });
```

the above code gives me 0,75. Great, except if i place an onClickListener there to get the location of the click (on the top left corner) I get 0,275.

Whats interesting is that if i do that same process in the onClickListener, I get 0,275 for the top left corner. Any clues on what I am doing wrong, or if there is a better place to put the code to fetch the location. It has to be after the view is drawn (for obvious reasons).

Thanks!

Comment: check TouchEvent.getRawX() and getRawY()

Comment: and do you mean by after its drawn = after its laid (inflated and for position on screen)?

Comment: I don't want to rely on the use touching it. That was just for debugging. Yes by drawn I mean fully inflated and visible

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this problem. I am not sure what the end goal here, but here are they:

1. Extend view and override onDraw for example or any other method you need
2. Like you said, call it onClick, since by that time UI is layout and rendered properly

Comment: the first idea is a good one which I'll try. Sadly the onClick is only for debugging. I cant wait for the user to click the view before i do that. But ill try overriding the onDraw and see where that goes. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, if this is only specific view, then I would definitely do custom view class. Otherwise there is other listener also available: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnDrawListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener)